# marginal probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory

Three balanced coins are tossed independently; one of the variables of interest is $X$, the number of heads. Let $Y$ denote the amount of money own on a side bet in the following manner: if first head occurs in the first toss, you win \$1. If the first head occurs in the second toss, you win \$2. If the first head occur in toss third, you win \$3. If no head occurs, you lose \$1. Find the joint probability function for $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

The joint probability will be a piecewise function $f(X,Y)$ where support of X is $\{0,1,2,3\}$ and support of Y is $\{1,2,3,-1\}$ where for each possible (X,Y) you have to find probability of that combo happening it may help to note that 
$$P(X=x,Y=y)=P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)$$
and that marginal distribution of $X\sim Bin(3,\frac{1}{2})$

There may also be an explicit formula but this is one way to do it

Comment: This is nearly an explicit formula, and certainly the best way anyway

Comment: Yea I was trying to see if there was to condense to one formula kinda like one would do for Bernoulli

Comment: Oh I hate the Bernoulli formula saying "$0$ or $1$" is so much better than $p^{x}(1-p)^{x}$ where $x$ is restricted to $\{0,1\}$